# Use PowerPivot table as parameter in another SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2010, powerpivot

I have information from 2 different SQL Server 2008 databases.

`DB1` has the following related tables with Employee information

- Employee
- empDepartment
- empLocation

`DB2` has a table `Refunds` with refund requests.

Since they are on different Databases, I'm planning on using PowerPivot to create cross DB pivot tables to be able to show things like Refund requests by department, etc.

I'm able to bring in all the data with no issues EXCEPT for the `Employee` table. I don't have access to the source data. I'm pulling from a data warehouse of sorts, and there happen to be duplicate employee IDs in the data (great!). I've tried `SELECT DISTINCT` queries but the entire row isn't duplicated, in most cases it's just a bad Employee ID.

The other issue, is that only a small portion of employees (1-2K) submit refund requests on behalf of customers, so it seems silly to pull in the entire employee table (200k records).

So I got the crazy idea that I could dynamically pull the `Employee` table using the employeeID column in the `Refunds` table. But I can't seem to find a place to use existing PowerPivot tables in a separate PowerPivot query.

Here is the SQL for how I'm currently pulling the employee information

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  emp.NTLogin as 'Employee_NTLogin'
  , emp.LastName + ', ' + emp.FirstName as Emp_FullName
  , emp.PositionCode as 'Position'
  , emp.DepartmentID as 'Department'
  , emp.LocationID as 'Location'
  , emp.HireDate as 'Employee_HireDate'
  , emp.EndDate as 'Employee_EndDate'
FROM dbo.Employee emp
WHERE
  emp.EndDate IS NULL
  OR emp.EndDate BETWEEN '04/01/2014 00:00:00' AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY 
  emp.LastName + ', ' + emp.FirstName
```

(the `WHERE` clause is filtering out employees that were current employees from 4/1 to today)

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of info about the actual pivot table you are using but here is an example of how to grab the data, you'll have to edit to match your tables.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Employee").PivotItems("ID").DataRange.Select
```

You'll probably want to place that data into an array and then pass that to your sql query. Not a complete answer, but hopefully it will get you on the path.